# A strange inductive proof: Induction on $n$, for all positive integers $n,n\ge1$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction

Prove by induction on $n$ that, for all positive integers $n, n\ge1$.

My Try:

Base case is true for $n=1$.

Inductive step:

$P(k)$ is true. $\implies k\ge1$

We need to show that $(k+1)\ge1$

From here how should I proceed.

Can anyone explain this strange inductive proof.

Comment: Hint: $k\ge 1 \Rightarrow k+1\ge 2$.

Answer (score 1):

$k\ge1\implies k+1\ge1+1=2\gt1$.